# Central limit theorem for sample proportions (Bernoulli trials)

Tags: normal-distribution, convergence, central-limit-theorem, bernoulli-distribution

*An student want to estimate*

$\phi(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx$.

*He made one computational experiment as follow:
Simulated the draw, with replacement, of 1000000 (one million) balls in a urn which contain 8 green balls and 2 red ones.*
*Repeated the above simulation 500000 (five hundred thousand) times.
One conclusion, at the end of experiment, was*

$\phi(0.51)\approx0.695$

- *Which theorems he used to made this experiment?*
- *Which results was obtained by simulation that led to the conclusion?*

My resolution:

\begin{equation}
  X_i=\begin{cases}
    1, & \text{if the $i^{th}$ ball is green}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

With

$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$

it's possible to use Strong Law of Large Number, then

$\frac{S_n}{n} \rightarrow \mu\;(almost\;surely)$, where

$\mu=E[X_i]=1*P(X_i=1)=8/10$.

So, considering such a large n in the simulation, we can assert that

$\frac{S_{10^6}}{10^6} \rightarrow \frac{8}{10}\;(a.s)$. This will be the proportion.

Now, to approximate the experiment to a normal distribution using Central Limit T.:

$\mu=p\\\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}\\n=500000$

$P(X\leq k) \overbrace{\approx}^{c.l.t}\Large{P(Z} \leq \frac{k-8/10}{\sqrt{\frac{.16}{500000}}})$

$\frac{k-.8}{\sqrt{\frac{.16}{500000}}}=.51\;\;\;(i)\\k=.80028849$

$P(X\leq .80028849) \approx P(Z\leq .51)=\phi(.51)$

There is a better way to reach the $\phi(.51)$, besides $i$? I'm not so conffident about this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed $S_n/n$ will be very close to $0.8$ but the law of large numbers is not the point of that question.

The point is to use the different draws of $S_n$ to simulate the normal distribution.

Here is a histogram of/disclaimer similar experiment results

[image: example]

I have colored the part red which corresponds to $\Phi(0.5)$. I found it by computing the mean and standard deviation of $S_n$. (your computations with $S_n/n$ are basically doing the same but make it more complicated)

---

Sidenote: Probably your lecturer/study-book wants you to claim that the central limit theorem was used in this experiment. But, the central limit theorem is more specifically only the limit of a sum when the number of terms goes to infinity. The central limit theorem *might* be used in the approximation of finite sums of variables, but it is not guaranteed to work very well.

In the case of a finite sum of Bernoulli variables, then we could also point to the simpler [Moivre Laplace theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem).

Some variables are not very well approximated with a normal distribution, even though they are a sum of many terms. (I know that there are some examples on the forum here, like sums of t-distributed variables, but I can't find the examples quickly)

Comment: So, you didn't use the sample proportion, just the c.l.t. directly?

Comment: @dori yes, apply the c.l.t directly. The numbers $2,8,10^6,5\cdot 10^5$ in the exercise where probably chosen with a direct application in mind. The mean and standard deviation are easy to compute in that way.

Comment: +1.  But because we see so much confusion on this site concerning what the CLT says and how one applies it, consider attributing this approach to the *Normal approximation to the Binomial distribution* rather than the CLT.

Comment: @whuber the central limit theorem is specifically about the *limit* at infinity of sums of variables. But the principle behind it resonates in many approximations of distributions when the sum is finite, indeed such as the de [Moivre Laplace theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem). I see the problem/confusion with applying the CLT mostly in the troubles of recognizing whether the convergence is fast or slow and recognizing whether the limit at infinity is a good estimate for a practical finite case.

Comment: Right: the problem is that eight is not infinity and many people do not recognize the nuances you have expressed.  One can avoid the entire problem, and help stave off misconceptions, in the manner I suggested.